# Integrating interceptor to web requests in spring 3.0

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, interceptor

Currently I am working on a web project and using spring 3.0 with annotation bases controllers.

1. I am trying to use intercept for login.
2. No url can be directly hit but from login using interceptor.

I am able to write an interceptor which won't let pass anyone to move into website without giving required parameters for login. But problem is that, remaining pages can also be accessed directly.

I am sharing with you my servlet.xml

I am also wondering why I have to defien URL mappings to get interceptor working, otherwise it goes into a unlimited loop.

please help me out in solving this issue, if you have any working example for this requirement, then please share it too.

Thank you in advance.

springmvc-servlet.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.waqas.app.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>



        <bean id="urlMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="urlMap">
            <map>
        <!--  -->   
            <entry key="contacts.htm"><ref bean="contactController" /></entry>
                    <entry key="users.htm"><ref bean="loginController" /></entry>

                            <entry key="hello.htm"><ref bean="helloController" /></entry>


            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean name="contactController" class="com.waqas.app.controller.ContactController" />

        <bean name="helloController" class="com.waqas.app.controller.HelloWorldController" />


   <bean name="loginController" class="com.waqas.app.controller.LoginController" />



        <bean id="handlerMapping"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="loginInterceptor"/>
            </list>
        </property>
          <property name="mappings">
            <value>

            *.htm=contactController

            </value>
        </property>

    </bean>



    <bean id="loginInterceptor"
          class="com.waqas.app.interceptor.LoginInterceptor">

    </bean>






</beans>
```

index.html

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>
<jsp:forward page="contacts.htm"></jsp:forward>
```

i also want to apply this interceptor on sepcific URLs/url pattern.

Looking forward to your reply.

Kind Regards,
qasibeat

Comment: How about using Spring Security Filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a common problem. Scott Murphy has created a nice spring plugin that allows to specify interceptor on a controller based on URLs. You can download it from [springplugins](http://code.google.com/p/springplugins/downloads/list).

Also see [Spring Framework Annotation-based Controller Interceptor Configuration](http://www.scottmurphy.info/spring_framework_annotation_based_controller_interceptors)

**EDIT:** For version 3.1+, see my answer to the question [Control Access to Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514170) to configure interceptor based on URL patterns.

Answer (score 0):

A Performance Monitor Interceptor Example. It logs whenever a request takes over 2seconds.

```
public class PerformanceMonitorHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

        private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( PerformanceMonitorHandlerInterceptor.class );

        /** Default to not active and 2 seconds. */
        private boolean active = true;

        /** The threshold. */
        private long threshold = 2000;

        /**
         * Starts the StopWatch to time request.
         * @param handler the handler
         * @param request the request
         * @param response the response
         * @return true, if pre handle
         * @throws Exception the exception
         * @see org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor#preHandle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,
         *      java.lang.Object)
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
                // Start Watch
                if ( this.active ) {
                        String name = this.createRequestTraceName( request );
                        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch( name );
                        stopWatch.start( name );
                        StopWatchHolder.setStopWatch( stopWatch );
                }

                // Continue with request
                return true;
        }

        /**
         * Warn if method takes longer than threshold milliseconds.
         * @param handler the handler
         * @param request the request
         * @param modelAndView the model and view
         * @param response the response
         * @throws Exception the exception
         * @see org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor#postHandle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,
         *      java.lang.Object, org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView)
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
                if ( this.active ) {
                        // Stop Watch
                        StopWatch stopWatch = StopWatchHolder.getStopWatch();
                        stopWatch.stop();

                        // Check threshold and log if over
                        if ( stopWatch.getLastTaskTimeMillis() >= this.threshold ) {
                                logger.warn( stopWatch.shortSummary() );
                        }

                        // Set ThreadLocal to null
                        StopWatchHolder.clear();
                }
        }

        /**
         * Not implemented.
         * @param handler the handler
         * @param exception the exception
         * @param request the request
         * @param response the response
         * @throws Exception the exception
         * @see org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor#afterCompletion(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,
         *      java.lang.Object, java.lang.Exception)
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception exception) throws Exception {
        // not implemented
        }

        /**
         * Creates the request trace name.
         * @param request the request
         * @return trace name
         */
        protected String createRequestTraceName(HttpServletRequest request) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append( "url: [" );
                sb.append( request.getRequestURL() );
                sb.append( "]" );
                sb.append( "  query: [" );
                sb.append( request.getQueryString() );
                sb.append( "]" );
                return sb.toString();
        }

        /**
         * Sets the threshold.
         * @param threshold The threshold to set.
         */
        public void setThreshold(long threshold) {
                this.threshold = threshold;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the active.
         * @param active The active to set.
         */
        public void setActive(boolean active) {
                this.active = active;
        }
}
```

Then plug the bean into your bean name url mapping:

```
    <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping">
            <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                    <ref bean="performanceMonitorHandlerInterceptor" />
                    </list>
            </property>
    </bean>
```