# Spring security - Access to a controller method based on an attribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm configuring Spring Security across all my controllers.
I want some method executions to start only when "my system is enabled". This information is accessible from all over the controllers via a specific static method (I can make it non-static).
My point is that I want to avoid making an explicit check in java code at the beginning of every method.
How can I get there via Spring Security?

Comment: How do you configure security acroos all your controllers? Do you use annotations on each method? Or xml config with multiple `intercpt-url` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a [handler interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html).

Here is general idea:

**(1)** Configure url patterns which you want to block:

```
<util:list id="sysEnableCheckUrlPatterns" value-type="java.lang.String">
    <beans:value>/module1/**</beans:value>
    <beans:value>/module2/**</beans:value>
</util:list>
```

**(2)** Write an interceptor:

```
    public class SysEnableCheckInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {


            /* 
                If system enabled then return true. Otherwise return false (and optionally write something in response)

            */
    }
}
```

**(3)** Configure that interceptor. In 3.1 you can do it as follows:

```
    @Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name="sysEnableCheckUrlPatterns")
    /* or use @Autowired or @Inject if you like */
    private String[] sysEnableCheckUrlPatterns;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

    registry.addInterceptor(new SysEnableCheckInterceptor()).addPathPatterns(sysEnableCheckUrlPatterns);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPEL (Spring Expression Language) in a security annotation.

See http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

Comment: Do I need to use a filter? Can I use @PreAuthorize and check a boolean value in a static variable stored elsewhere (not a parameter, nor in the class of the annotated method)?

Comment: I believe that you can, but I've never tried it. Give it a try, and let us know :-)